# Cross-product of date ranges

Tags: sql, postgresql, date, join

I have two tables containing date ranges that I want to cross multiply in a way to get all distinct ranges. That is, all ranges that have a boundary in one of the tables.

Specifically I have a table with product prices and their validity dates as well as conversion factors with a validity date. I want, as a result, each instance of a specific price/conversion_factor combination and from when to when it was valid:

```
products:
product_id  start_date  end_date    price_eur
1           2000-01-01  2000-12-31  100
1           2001-01-01  2002-12-31  150


conversion_factors:
start_date  end_date    dollar_to_eur
1970-01-01  2000-03-31  1.50
2000-04-01  2000-06-30  1.60
2000-07-01  2001-06-30  1.70
2001-07-01  2003-06-30  2.00

result:
product_id  start_date  end_date    price_eur   dollar_to_eur
1           2000-01-01  2000-03-31  100         1.50                
1           2000-04-01  2000-06-30  100         1.60                
1           2000-07-01  2000-12-31  100         1.70                
1           2001-01-01  2001-06-30  150         1.70                
1           2001-07-01  2002-12-31  150         2.00
```

So each time one of the tables hits a new date, a new row should be returned. In the result the first two rows reference the validity of the first product row, but split up into two intervals in the conversion_factos table. Similarly the second and third row of the result come from the second conversion factor row, but with different product rows.

Is there any way to do this with a clever join (in PostgreSQL) or do I need to use a PL/pgSQL function?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are to parts in this, you ask for a smart join and you ask for displaying the correct result. This should answer your problems:

```
SELECT Greatest(p.start_date, cf.start_date) AS start_date
      ,Least(p.end_date, cf.end_date) AS end_date
      ,p.price_eur
      ,cf.dollar_to_eur
FROM products AS p
  JOIN conversion_factors AS cf
    ON p.start_date <= cf.end_date AND p.end_date >= cf.start_date
```